# What is the appropriate input shape for a 2D CNN-based network?

Tags: python, image, conv-neural-network, shapes, training-data

I am having trouble passing the appropriate input shape to a CNN-based network with a Conv2D layer.
Initially, these are my train shapes. My train data is reshaped into windows:

`X_train: (7,100,5185)= (number of features, window size, number of windows)`

`y_train= (5185, 100 ) = one labeled column that is also windowed`

I then calculate some **Recurrence plots** from this data, I will then have these shapes:

`X_train_rp= (5185, 100,100, 7), 100 * 100 referring to my images`

`y_train =  (5185, 100 ), remains unchanged`

I pass these two to a conv2D-based CNN with:

`model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 7)))`

And I get this error:  **`Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 100, 100, 100 ......... y sizes: 5185 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.`**

I tried many combinations of shapes but in vain! What am I doing wrong ??

**EDIT**:
This is the model definition using

```py
import tensorflow as tf

X_train_rp = tf.zeros((10, 100,100, 7))
y_train =  tf.zeros((10, 100))

#create model 
model = tf.keras.Sequential() #add model layers    
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',
                                 data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(100, 100, 7))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten()) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')) 

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_rp, y_train_shaped, epochs=3)
model.predict(X_train_rp)
```

Comment: If the question is just about shapes, the first two code blocks could be exluded from the question, as only the actual input shape of `X_train_rp` and `y_train` is relevant. On the otherhand, the most relevant part, namely your model definition must be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the used module aliases I assume you use the tensorflow keras package with a sequential model definition. Your assumptions about the input shapes are actually correct demonstrated by this code snippet adapted from the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_shape = (10, 100, 100, 7)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
print(y.shape)
>>> (10, 98, 98, 64)
```

This means the problem lies within your sequential model definition. Please update your question and include the necessary code.

**EDIT**:
Using the model definition provided by OP with a small modification yields a working training process. The issue lies in the definition of the dense layer, which takes the `output` nodes as first positional argument and not the input dimensions.

For the sake of computational cost I reduced the number of training examples from (5185) to (10)...

```py
import tensorflow as tf

X_train_rp = tf.zeros((10, 100,100, 7))
y_train =  tf.zeros((10, 100))

#create model 
model = tf.keras.Sequential() #add model layers    
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',
                                 data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(100, 100, 7))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten()) 

# Here comes the fix:
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='softmax')) 

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_rp, y_train, epochs=3)
```

Comment: Alright, now I get it :D thanks!!